# Redis in-memory data Storage

Tags: redis, in-memory-database

Redis is a database in-memory but persistent on disk meanwhile.

**Q1:** So I wonder does this mean that when redis server starts, it will automatically load all the data on the disk into memory?

**Q2:** And when writing data to redis, will it both update in the memory and the disk?

Can anyone please help me answer my two questions?

Comment: The answer to your questions are [here](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: So I wonder does this mean that when redis server starts, it will
>   automatically load all the data on the disk into memory?

Yes, depending on the configuration, Redis performs snapshots of memory to disk and, when Redis is restarted it can take latest snapshot and take it to memory again automatically.

> Q2: And when writing data to redis, will it both update in the memory
>   and the disk?

Redis prioritizes writes on memory and writes to disk are done in a separate thread. The answer then is **yes, it writes data to both memory and disk**, but it might happen that a server failure may produce a data loss since it's not mandatory to Redis to persist data to disk.

Check official docs [about persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) to learn more about the topic.